# UIRefreshControl appears on top of collection view items instead of behind

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UICollectionView` with the regular pull to refresh implementation, but somehow the spinner and the "pull to refresh" text appear above the collection view items;

How can I make it behind the items?

This is how I add the `UIRefreshControll` to the `UICollectionView`

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull down to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
collectionView?.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The way I figure this out is to change the `refreshControll` `zPosition` to be behind every view with the following:

```
refreshControl.layer.zPosition = -1
```

Hope this helps anyone further.

Comment: note: current fix doesn't fix position of header view of table(collection)View during scrolling. Header view shifts vertically on height of refresh control.
Use setRefreshControl instead of addSubview. Works on >= iOS 10

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your question! I have the same issue, hoping this solution still works on later iOS versions

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var refresher:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

    let refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    self.refresher.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadData), for: .valueChanged)
    self.collectionView!.addSubview(refresher)
}

func loadData() {
   //code to execute during refresher
       .
       .
       .
   stopRefresher()         //Call this to stop refresher
 }

func stopRefresher() {
   self.refresher.endRefreshing()
 }
```